# Google Admob Ads not showing at all

Tags: admob, ads

I have been using admob for quite a time. I have two published apps on play store. Initially **Match Rate** was good and ads were showing properly. Suddenly match rate dropped to below 10% and now there are plenty of requests but ads are not showing at all. 
(I have almost 500+ daily new installs with 7k+ ads requests to admob resulting in max 100 impressions). I'm worried a lot please guys guide or suggest any solution for this.